# Proof that F is differentiable with respect to $\lambda$ and: $\frac{dF}{d\lambda}=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{df}{d\lambda}(s,\lambda)ds $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

> Let: 
>   $$F(x,\lambda)=\int_{a}^{x}f(s,\lambda)ds$$
>   Assume that f is differentiable with respect to $\lambda$. Proof that F is differentiable with respect to $\lambda$ and:
>
> $$\frac{dF}{d\lambda}=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{df}{d\lambda}(s,\lambda)ds $$

I have an idea, and in order for $F (x, \lambda)$ to exist, the integral of $f(s, \lambda)$ must exist with respect to s. And that could lead us to demonstrate the derivative of F with respect to $\lambda$, but I don't know how to continue from there.

Comment: First, "proof" is a noun, not a verb!  You mean "prove that" (sorry, but I see "proof that" so often it has become a pet peeve.)

Comment: Have you learned dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. What is the theorem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider the definition of the derivative, i.e. 
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_a^x f(s, \lambda + h) ds - \int_a^x f(s, \lambda) ds}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_a^x \frac{f(s, \lambda + h) - f(s, \lambda)}{h} ds $$
and argue why you can swap limit and integral.